# nginx config to only allow access to specific files

Tags: php, nginx

I'm very new to nginx (just migrating from Apache and .htaccess files), and my setup is quite specific. I want to:

1. allow access to index.html, /build, /images, /api/public/index.php
   ONLY
2. funnel all requests to index.html UNLESS the file exists in
   /images or /build
3. EXCEPT any requests into the /api folder, which
   must all be funneled to /api/public/index.php.

index.php is my API front controller, and though that will open a million other PHP files, my understanding is the HTTP requester won't need access to those.

So, where to even begin?